# Eclipse Web Development - What plugins to install and how to get Dojo, Ajax - WYSIWYG development

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, dojo, wysiwyg

Eclipse Java Web Development - What plugins to install and how to get Dojo, Ajax - WYSIWYG development working. I have been struggling a long time to get web development going on eclipse - I am not interested in Aptana or Netbeans or Dojo's Maquetta - please tell me how to configure any version of eclipse -Helios, Indigo, Juno to have dojo, javascipt, html, jsp servlet working with WYSISWYG.

Your help is very very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Q: Why aren't you interested in Aptana (for example)?  Eclipse => Aptana plugin for Eclipse => Dojo plugin for Aptana can be an effective tool.  DEFINITELY: download Firefox, and install the Firebug plugin.  Firefox/Firebug is arguably your *single* most effective tool for debugging Javascript, Ajax ... and, of course, Dojo.  IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

You can download Eclipse Java EE package from Eclipse Downloads site. You can refer to this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php) for a more detailed comparison of different eclipse packages.

It comes along with JavaScript Development Toolkit(JSDT)  and WST (Web Started Toolkit) which will help you get started with web development. I believe WST toolkit also contains a WYSIWYG editor for creating html pages.